# Suggestion for calculating the limit $\lim\limits_{m \to\infty} \frac{m!}{m^{m/2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I tried to use the limit $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{n!}{n^n}$ but I couldn't.

I am interested in calculating the limit $$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)!(2n-1)}{(2n)^{n}}=\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n)!(2n-1)}{(2n)^{n}}\frac{1}{(2n)}=\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)^{n}} \frac{(2n-1)}{(2n)}$$.

Hence I only need the limit. $$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(2n)^{n}}$$

Well, the limit $$\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \frac{(2n-1)}{(2n)}=1$$

So I couldn't solve it. Help, please.

Comment: Please don't repost closed questions, instead edit the previous one and ask to be reopened

Comment: delete your closed question.

Comment: You can include these extra details in the similar question [What's the limit of the sequence $\lim\limits_{m \to\infty} \frac{m!}{m^{m/2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4824164/89922).

Comment: @Mike no need to downovote, maybe OP does not know the rules

Comment: Given that this question has an answer, and is phrased better than your old question, in this circumstance, I would advise you to just delete your old question. For the next time though, follow Sine of the Time's advice and edit your question rather than reposting.

Comment: @Takashi: perhaps you should delete this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4824164/121671) of yours which was closed and ask the same question as the present posting. Having a duplicate question sometimes brings downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can write $\frac{(2n-1)!(2n-1)}{(2n)^n}$ as
$$\frac{(2n-1)(2n-2)\dots(2n-n)(n-1)!(2n-1)}{(2n)(2n)\times\dots\times(2n)}\\
=(1-1/2n)(1-1/n)\dots(1-1/2)(n-1)!(2n-1)$$
and since $\frac{1}{2}<1-k/2n<1$ for every $k=1,\dots,n$, it becomes clear that the referred limit must be $+\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

This is one possible approach:

Consider $a_n=\frac{n!}{n^{n/2}}$. Then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=(n+1)\frac{n^{n/2}}{(n+1)^{n/2}(n+1)^{1/2}}=\sqrt{n+1}\frac{1}{\big(1+\frac1n\big)^{n/2}}
$$

The factor $\frac{1}{\big(1+\frac1n\big)^{n/2}}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}e^{-1/2}$ and so, $a_{n+1}/a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$. This implies that for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$a_{n+1}>2a_n>0\qquad n\geq N$$
From this, it follows that
$$a_{N+m}\geq 2^m a_N,\qquad m\in\mathbb{N}$$
Thus $\lim_na_n=\infty$